# Why do I have "if" expression expected error?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm very new to coding and I am learning python alone and this is my code :

```py
from random import *
temp =Randint( 0,70 )
print(temp)
if : temp = 69
print("nice")
```

Comment: `if :  temp = 69` doesn't make sense.  Did you mean `if temp == 69:` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You made a few errors

1. randint is a function so it's first letter should be small case
2. The for loop syntax was wrong
3. And we use == for checking equality and = for assignment

You can try the following code below

```
from random import randint

temp = randint( 0,70 ) 
print(temp) 
if temp == 69:
    print("nice")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement isn't quite right. The colon needs to go at the end of the line, and in an if statement you need a double equals sign (`==`, which *compares* two elements) rather than a single equals sign (which *assigns* a variable). Additionally, you need to indent (put a <kbd>tab</kbd> before) lines that are part of a block. You can read more about Python if statements [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_if_statement.asp). The fixed if statement should look like this:

```
if temp == 69: 
    print("nice")
```

Lastly, since Python names are case-sensitive, `randint` must be in all lowercase.

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A quick thing to remember is that “==“ means two things are equal and “!=“ means if something is not equal.